# Eigen faces using PCA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pca, feature-extraction

I am trying to implement Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to extract the features from the image in MATLAB. I have implemented the following code.

```
[Rows, Columns] = size(x);  % find size of input matrix
m=mean(x);                  % find mean of input matrix
y=x-ones(size(x,1),1)*m;    % normalise by subtracting mean
c=cov(y);                   % find covariance matrix
[V,D]=eig(c);               % find eigenvectors (V) and eigenvalues (D) of covariance matrix
[D,idx] = sort(diag(D));    % sort eigenvalues in descending order by first diagonalising eigenvalue matrix, idx stores order to use when ordering eigenvectors
D = D(end:-1:1)';
V = V(:,idx(end:-1:1));     % put eigenvectors in order to correspond with eigenvalues
V2d=V(:,1:200);        % (significant Principal Components we use, OutputSize is input variable)
prefinal=V2d'*y';
final=prefinal';            % final is normalised data projected onto eigenspace
imshow(final);
```

I want to know that how can I check the 1st Eigen faces,2nd Eigen faces.. etc

EDIT:
Here is the [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0k0P.png) and the Eigen Image is [Eigen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyDnb.png)

Comment: Can you also show in the code the previous steps? What is `x`?

Comment: `img=imread( 'KA.AN1.39.tiff');
x=double(img);`

Comment: Are you computing the PCA with a single image? Why? the "eigenfaces" thing only works with several images....

Comment: To be more clear. If there is a sigle image you are using, and you dont unroll it (`x=img(:);`) PCA will interpret that each of the rows of your image is a different set of data. This makes no sense for images.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actally i want to take features from each image so that i make the feature vector and then i do use some classification to recognize the emotions

Comment: Cognrats, but you are doing it wrong. You need to learn better what you are doing! eigenfaces will only appear when you do PCA of a series of images. Actually a PCA of a single image will gie you no information about the image, I doubt you can classify anything with that.

Comment: @AnderBiguri so can you suggest me what will be the best way to extract features from image using PCA?

Comment: Not with PCA. But that would be ovbious if you understood PCA! I reccomend you read some papers/books! Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first eigenface is the first eigenvector!

My guess, is that with your code:

```
eigenface1=reshape(V(:,1),rows,cols);
```

as, if your code is right, each eigenvector should be the same size as your input images, but unrolled. I am assuming that `rows` and `cols` are the size of the image.

Comment: can you check the input image and out put eigen image, V(:,1) is 256x1 and rows=16 col=16

Comment: The eigenfaces looks somethink lieke this @ShinningEyes http://rduin.nl/manual/images/face_classification_fig_2.png . Make sure you show them as `imshow(eigenface1,[])` to maximize the visual output